# What is the : division by 0 (error token is "etc/shadow ") error?

Tags: bash

I am a beginner at Bash scripting and I am getting an error saying this when I run my code:

*main.sh: line 7: ((: -w /etc/shadow : division by 0 (error token is "etc/shadow ")*

The following is the code I wrote in main.sh:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

if [ -e /etc/shadow ]
then
    echo "Shadow passwords are enabled."

    if (( -w /etc/shadow ))
    then
        echo "You have permissions to edit /etc/shadow"
    else
        echo "You do NOT have permissions to edit /etc/shadow"
    fi
else
    echo "Shadow passwords are not enabled."
fi
```

The result after running the code also gave:

*Shadow passwords are enabled.*

*You do NOT have permissions to edit /etc/shadow*

This was given before the error message. Does anyone have any suggestions for how to fix this problem and what the error message means? Thanks!

Comment: Use `[ .. ]` instead of `(( .. ))` for `[ -w /etc/shadow ]`. `((..))` is for math, and you are writing a math expression `-x/y/z` where x=w and y=etc, where `etc` isn't set and therefore 0, causing the division by 0 error

Comment: https://shellcheck.net for validating shell scripts.

Comment: @SaianshSingh : In `(( -w /etc/shadow ))` you divide the variable `etc` by `shadow`, because `/` is the division operator in numeric context. Since you did not assign a value to these variables, bash assumes that they are 0.

Comment: Thanks, everyone, that really worked!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `[[ ... ]]` (preferred, bash-only) or `[ ... ]` (can cause problems, POSIX compliant) instead of `(( ... ))`: they are adequate for comparing text, while `(( ... ))` is an arithmetic context and only accepts mathematical operations. The error occurs because it tries to use the `/`s in the path for division.

That error counts as a false for the if, making you run the `else` block.

```
if [[ -w /etc/shadow ]]
then
# ...
```

A good reference for using `if` in bash is the [Bash Beginner Guide](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_07_01.html).